# Android Secure Keystore pre-API 19

Tags: cryptography, android, key-management

Is there any secure Keystore for Android other than [Android Keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html)?

If an attacker used an emulator, saving a key in SharedPreferences or storage is pretty much useless since she'll have direct access to it, this eliminating any use of the key.

How would you tackle such an issue?

Comment: Ask the user for a passphrase and encrypt with something based off of it. Or, hope that the user's device does not wind up in the hands of an attacker.